# Blocked exit node keeps coming back!

Tags: exit-relays, blocked

I got several exit nodes blocked by country in my "torrc defaults" file.

This is what the script looks like:

> StrictNodes 1
>
> ExitNodes {ru}
>
> ExcludeExitNodes {us},{ca},{gb},{ua},{se},{de},{es},{lu},{ch},{fr},{nl},{??}

So usually the code works, and I'm getting only Russian-based exit nodes.

BUT there's a recurrent problem... An exit node hosted by Digital Ocean, that is firstly identified as from "NL", yet being actually from New York City, keeps coming back sporadically as the exit node.

I have been reinstalling Tor and checking the signatures... no change. How the hell can "NL" exit nodes still pass through when they've been blocked already, and only "RU" exit nodes supposed to pass?

Obviously this node is a bad apple, though how to get rid of it?

I'll also try to submit this as a bug.

Comment: Could you tell which exit node this is? If you want to exclude one particular node you can use `ExcludeExitNodes 1234567890ABDEF…` where the latter one is the fingerprint of the node.

Comment: "Obviously this node is a bad apple." It isn't obvious to me.

Comment: Should you file this as a bug report can you link it, probably answer the question with it?

Comment: Have you reported this as a bug or otherwise found a solution? It would be nice if you could share what you know.

Comment: I decided to close this question, because it is not reproducible here and the original poster doesn't answer the comments. So it seems hard to get a good answer to the question.